# stream.listeners is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to run a **really** basic Express app, I'm getting this error:

```
/path/to/testserver/node_modules/unpipe/index.js:22
  var listeners = stream.listeners('data')
                         ^

TypeError: stream.listeners is not a function
    at hasPipeDataListeners (/path/to/testserver/node_modules/unpipe/index.js:22:26)
    at unpipe (/path/to/testserver/node_modules/unpipe/index.js:52:8)
    at send (/path/to/testserver/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:311:3)
    at /path/to/testserver/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:133:5
    at Function.handle (/path/to/testserver/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:177:5)
    at app (/path/to/testserver/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:39:9)
    at file:///path/to/testserver/index.js:6:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
```

The app code is literally just:

```js
import express from "express";

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Is this thing on?");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${port}...`);
});
```

I bootstrapped the project like this:

```
npm init -y
npm install express
```

...and then added `"type": "module"` to `package.json` (but I know the problem isn't ESM; I removed that and switched to `require` and had the same problem).

Why am I getting that error? I don't see that error message in [the issues list](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues).

Comment: This question was inspired by a question posted by someone else earlier but deleted before it could be answered. I thought it was worth having an explanation for it here on SO, so I've posted this and the community wiki answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo-level mistake, but the symptom is so bizarre and the typo so subtle that it's worth having an answer about it here. The problem is here:

```js
    app("/", (req, res) => {
//  ^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
        res.send("Is this thing on?");
    });
```

That **calls** `app`. The code should be calling one of `app`'s *methods*, like `app.get`:

```js
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//  ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
        res.send("Is this thing on?");
    });
```

Although it doesn't seem to be [documented](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app), `app` (the function) calls `app.handle`. From `node_modules/express/lib/express.js`:

```
var app = function(req, res, next) {
  app.handle(req, res, next);
};
```

`app.handle` expects very different parameters than `app.get` does. It happens that passing it `app.get` parameters takes it down a path to where eventually it reaches that error condition.

Just change `app(` to `app.get(` or whatever other method the code was meant to use.